# If an internal HDD is not mounted, is it still in function?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ssd

I have a probably stupid question, but I'm gonna try anyway

I have both a SSD and a HDD on my laptop: if my HDD is data only, and not mounted unless I need something inside (there's no "eject" icon next to it in Nautilus, just to be clear) is it still in function? 
I'm asking for a simple reason: since SSD have no moving parts, do I still need to be careful while moving my laptop because of the HDD? Or when it's not mounted the head is safely placed and there's no risk usually associated with moving a powered laptop with a working HDD?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If none of the partitions on your hard drive are in use (swap ?) , then yes the drive is not "in use". It can still be damaged if you hit or drop your box hard enough though ;)

Comment: So it's not spinning, it's in the same exact state it would be if it was sitting on my desk? Thanks a lot!

Comment: In theory, it should be powered down if it is not in use. Certainly this is the case with most any modern laptop, although I suppose there could always be a bug or unusual hardware configuration.

Comment: You can power down the drive not in use - there is some information in this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/194102/reducing-power-consumption-of-second-hdd

Comment: So it is not powered down, unless I do like in the link you wrote? I'm a bit confused